# How to get Readline to work with PDB in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdb

I'm using GoogleAppEngine SDK 1.9.30 on osX10.10.5, with readlineV6.2.4.1 and when I enter pdb.set_trace(), readline doesn't seem to be active.

When I start dev_appserver.py and enter the breakpoint, 
If I attempt to use the up arrow to recall earlier statements displays ^[[A or to correct a mistake on the same line with the back arrow prints ^[[D

How can I get readline working with pdb in App Engine?

EDIT: 
I believe the SDK has python modules designed to work with App Engine, so you can't just add the path to my local site-packages dir.

I tried adding just the required modules:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline.pyc')  
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gnureadline.so')  

import readline
```

I still got: 
   ImportError: No module named readline

Comment: use `pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: My mistake,I was using pdb.set_trace()

Comment: Try putting `import readline` right before your `pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: The Readline module is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/rlineimpl.py , but attempting to import into the App Engine project "ImportError: No module named readline"

Comment: It seems the Python runtime cannot find the module you seek. Is the module in fact at that location? If so, is this module path visible from `sys.path`? This How does python find packages?[1] article may prove helpful in determining this.
[1]: https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

Comment: I think there are specific python modules in the SDK that must be used so I can't just add the path to site-packages. I did try to add the path to the file:  sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline.py')
import readline

It did not work.

Comment: The `rlineimpl` module is not part of the standard GAE libs, so I believe in order to be accessible from the app in the SDK it needs to be vendored in with all its other 3rd party dependencies (if they all meet the sandbox requirements): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#vendoring